# Python joblib Parallel n_jobs=1 is working. n_jobs=2 is not working. No error. Empty output. nmslib model pipe

Tags: python, parallel-processing, data-science, spacy, joblib

Here is the code for creating tokens from the list of full names

```
import en_core_web_sm
from datetime import datetime
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from spacy.util import minibatch
from functools import partial

tok_text = [] # OUTPUT for our tokenised corpus
text = ["liam noah", "oliver william", "harper mason", "emma noah", "evelyn ethan", "mia lucas", "amelia benjamin", "isabella james", "sophia mason", "ava elijah"]

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

def process_texts(nlp, batch_id, text):
    print(f"{datetime.now()} Processing batch {batch_id}")
    for doc in nlp.pipe(text):
        tok = [t.text for t in doc if(t.is_ascii and not t.is_punct and not t.is_space)]
        tok_text.append(tok)

batch_size = 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Creating Parallel batches...")
    partitions = minibatch(text, size=batch_size)
    executor = Parallel(n_jobs=1)              #later will update it to n_jobs=2
    do = delayed(partial(process_texts, nlp))
    tasks = (do(i, batch) for i, batch in enumerate(partitions))
    executor(tasks)
    
print("Tokens:: ",tok_text)
```

Above code generates below output (Sequential batches):

```
Creating Parallel batches...
2021-01-26 14:20:18.852977 Processing batch 0
2021-01-26 14:20:18.870977 Processing batch 1
2021-01-26 14:20:18.886977 Processing batch 2
2021-01-26 14:20:18.900977 Processing batch 3
2021-01-26 14:20:18.918977 Processing batch 4
Tokens::  [['liam', 'noah'], ['oliver', 'william'], ['harper', 'mason'], ['emma', 'noah'], ['evelyn', 'ethan'], ['mia', 'lucas'], ['amelia', 'benjamin'], ['isabella', 'james'], ['sophia', 'mason'], ['ava', 'elijah']]
```

When I change the line to n_jobs=2

```
executor = Parallel(n_jobs=2)
```

It runs, no errors, but no work done...

```
Creating Parallel batches...
Tokens::  []  <== Empty output
```

What am I missing?

Comment: A [reprex] may help

Comment: Updated code to a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: 1st, it's working here with both `n_jobs=1` and `n_jobs=2`, so the error should be due to your environment. 2nd, what could be a reason to parallelize already parallel `nlp.pipe()`?

Comment: Same thing is happening when I use the `n_process=2` in `nlp.pipe()`
```
for doc in nlp.pipe(text, n_process=2):
    tok = [t.text for t in doc if(t.is_ascii and not t.is_punct and not t.is_space)]
    tok_text.append(tok)
```
It keeps on running... not returning....

Comment: I personally would start with checking versions of the packages, or installing env from scratch with a package manager like conda